# How to access index each element in list?

Tags: r

I work with a list of length `k` (e.g., `k = 4`) and a matrix. I'd like to access each element in a list without `for` and `while`. The list elements are index of matrix.

Toy problem

```
l <- list(x1 = 1:10, x2 = c(2,3,4,5,6), x3 = c(2, 5), x4 = c(3,2,1))
data <- matrix(rnorm(40), nrow = 10)
```

Output desired

```
data[l[[1]], ]
data[l[[2]], ]
data[l[[3]], ]
data[l[[4]], ]
```

Comment: You just want to print them? You don't want the "headers" from `print(l)`?
 Maybe just `invisible(Map(print, l))`?

Comment: I'd like these objects in a variable, e.g., step 1: `a <- l[[1]]` after I apply one operation and I discard `a`; step 2: `a <- l[[2]]` I apply other operation and I discard `a`; step 3 `a <- l[[3]]` I apply other operation and discard `a`; ...

Comment: `lapply(l, function(a) {other operation on a})`

Comment: That doesn't seem consistent with your described output above. Sounds like you want a `Map()` or `lapply()` function.

Comment: I think that it was being not clear.

Comment: So, perhaps this: `Map(function(i) data[i,], l)`?

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!